# Accessing Views Within Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a view for my website coded in RoR wherein all the available path are listed as links. Is there any way to access the views for various models from the program?

For example, something like:

```
<%model.views.each do |v| %>
<%= link_to v %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [sitemap_generator](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/master/frames) or [dynamic_sitemaps](https://github.com/lassebunk/dynamic_sitemaps) gem to generate Sitemaps for your application.

Comment: is there a way to automate it? It looks like I need to type in each view separately, which in my case is quite cumbersome.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You should add the required routes in `sitemap.rb` file to generate the sitemap.

Comment: after researching a bit more I realized the a site map is not quite what I want. I want a view which basically lists all the available pages to go to as links the viewer can click on. It seems that a site map generally refers to an XML file for crawlers, which isn't actually meant to be viewed by humans. Is this true?

Comment: And is there any way to implement what I would like to do, besides manually making a separate link_to for every path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use named routes, which allows you to create a link to a different part of your rails app, based on names you set in routes.rb. You can also include route parameters, too, which makes it easy to link to models.

In your `routes.rb`

```
get 'test_route/:id' => 'example#controller', as :test
```

In controllers/views:

```
link_to @example.name, test_path(id: @example.id)
```

Further reading on [named routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html#module-ActionDispatch::Routing-label-Named+routes)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you want this :), but this will give you the routes

`Rails.application.routes.routes`

if you want to get all the paths as an array

`Rails.application.routes.routes.collect {|r| r.path.spec.to_s }`